# CSS "depth meter" (div that follows screen and changes numbers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone have idea how to make little div with small image lets say 50x50 px to follow scrolling inside of webpage (lets say its centered verticaly and hugging one side of screen) + beside that div it changes numbers from top of screen 0 to bottom 100. Something similar i found on this page but cant see how this works
http://www.jana-water.com/hr/o-jani . If anyone has idea how to make it would be gr8.I googled it but dont know what that "technique" is called.

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/PiranhaGreg/Ggn7R ?

Comment: ah silly me.. so just by fixed.. yes that.. do you know any idea how to add that counter? so it changes value with scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/zzkf5/1/

JavaScript to get the 'depth':

```
var depthMeter = $('#depthMeter');

$(window).scroll(function(){
    depthMeter.text($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

CSS to get the element fixed on the right:

```
#depthMeter {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;

    margin-top: -25px; // Half the height, because top: 50% does not factor in the element's height

    height: 50px;
    width: 50px; 
}
```

Comment: you sir got it to the spot :)) thanx alot!